# Content Query Web Part: Lookup Column Value and XSL

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part

There is a List with Lookup field. And there is a **CQWP** web part which uses this list as a Source and uses custom **XSL** style added to `Itemstyle.xsl`. 
And there is a problem how to render this field as a link?

Field name is `Vegetable` and

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Vegetable" />
```

Returns a string with item's title (like 'Potato'). Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
I've found [an article with similar problem](http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2010/07/206/).
And here is a comment form it:

> We raised a call with Microsoft PSS in the end and we’ve been told
>   today by PSS after consulting with the SharePoint dev team that this
>   is a known issue and that Custom Fields using the People or Groups
>   field type do NOT work with the CQWP, only out of the box fields.
>
> The workaround above does work, however further tests show it’s not
>   reliable and is very situational.

Comment: You shouldn't put the answer inside the question. You should put your answer in the answer field, mark it, so it'll be closed

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this?

```
<a href="/Lists/lookuplist/dispform.aspx?id={substring-before(@Vegetable,';#')}" ><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@Vegetable,'#')" /></a>
```

Comment: For some reason the value of attribute Vegetable is like 'Potato' but it should be like 'Potato;1'.